# BIRT FILTER FOR DAY OF THE WEEK FROM RTC TIMESTAMP

Tags: report, birt, rational-team-concert

I want to write a birt filter to just get database entries for a particular day of the week/month. I want to filter them at source. Is there any "sql like" syntax that allows to get the day of the week from `TIMESTAMP`?

Something like....

```
PROJECT_AREA_NAME = '{Current Project Area}' AND ITERATION_NAME = ITNAME AND  WI_TYPE = 'Bug'  AND DAYOFTHEWEEK(TIMESTAMP) = 1
```

Thanks in advance
John

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you are trying to do? Do you want a number for your SQL query ?

Comment: I want to just get entries back for a particular day every week - i know i can filter the data in the client but i'd rather just have the server send me 1/7 less records